# Specifying communication protocols

Tags: documentation, communication, specifications

I am trying to document the communication between two existing systems that today is pretty bad Specified. I wonder if there is any standard or best practice to document network communication protocol I can use?
There are several special types that must be documented and mixed bit order

The communication is quite simple, it's like this (pseudo code)

**System A->System B** (initiate communication)

```
  short type;                   //Little endian
```

**System B->System A**

```
  short type;                   //Little endian
  short count;                  //Little endian
  //Start time
  short NoOfDaysSince1970;      //Big endian
  int   noOfMillisecoundsToday; //Big ending
  if(type==1)
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      char[20] name;
  else
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      float value;    //platform specific float, Little ending
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      short flag;                //Big ending
  //Stop time
  short noOfDaysSince1970;       //Big ending
  int   noOfMillisecoundsToday;  //Big ending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [Abstract Syntax Notation One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).